# How to prevent IEDriverServer.exe process to launch multiple times?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and IE Web Driver. Whenever my test starts, IE Driver Server starts too, but it doesn't close/exit after test finishes. So for the next test run, I end up with multiple instances of `IEDriverServer.exe` processes sitting around. How do I close it after test run?

Below is the sample code I use:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var ie = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver(new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions() {
             IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
        });
        ie.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:50640/");
        ie.Close();
        ie.Close(
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I know I can use `ProcessInfo` to kill it, but it'll be nice to have a Selenium solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `ie.Quit();`?

Please refer to the [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) and the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#365).

`Quit()` is the one to quit completely (the browser and the driver).

`Close()` is for closing the browser window. This is why here in your case, the `IEDriverServer.exe` is left open.

**`IWebDriver.cs`**

```
/// <summary>
/// Close the current window, quitting the browser if it is the last window currently open.
/// </summary>
void Close();

/// <summary>
/// Quits this driver, closing every associated window.
/// </summary>
void Quit();
```

**`RemoteWebDriver.cs`** (which is the base class of **`InternetExplorerDriver.cs`**)

```
/// <summary>
/// Closes the Browser
/// </summary>
public void Close()
{
    this.Execute(DriverCommand.Close, null);
}

/// <summary>
/// Close the Browser and Dispose of WebDriver
/// </summary>
public void Quit()
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```